# Why the writer used present prefect with in the last year

Tags: tense

I was reading an article and I noticed that the writer used in the last year + present perfect? As I learned we can't use the present perfect with last year, last week, etc.

The sentence: "in the last year there have been rapid changes and businesses have been forced to pivot to agile strategies in a bid to survive."

Answer (score 3):

It's not just a mere description of an event that took place (and finished) in the past. These changes have impacted the present - the effect they have had (and, perhaps, continue to have) on businesses is still perceivable. This process of adaptation is ongoing.